# Is there an algebraic solution for the differential equation $y'= x^y$, and if not, can we prove this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I believe that no algebraic solution exists, however, can we prove this?

Below I have plotted the (real part) of the direction field on
$[-3 < x < 3]\times [ -3 < y < 3 ]$

[image]