# Is $y’=x^y\implies xy’’-x\ln(x)y’^2-yy’=0,y’=y^x\implies xy'(x)^4-y(x)y'(x)^2 \left(xy''(x)+2y'(x)\right)+y(x)^2\left(y'''(x)y'(x)-y''(x)^2\right)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, fourier-series, exponentiation, nonlinear-analysis

Here is a partial inspiration for this question:

> [ODE: $$y''y+ax+by+c=0,y=k\pm\sqrt2\int\sqrt{a\int\ln(y)dx-(ax+c)\,\ln(y)-by+K}dx,\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{K-(ax+c)\,\ln(y)+a\int\ln(y)dx-by}}=k\pm\sqrt2x$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241691/ode-yyaxbyc-0-y-k-pm-sqrt2-int-sqrta-int-lnydx-axc-lny-bykdx)

and

> [Is there an algebraic solution for the differential equation $y'= x^y$, and if not, can we prove this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089779/is-there-an-algebraic-solution-for-the-differential-equation-y-xy-and-if-n?noredirect=1)

this is the same question, but has no current answer and only asks for a proof for a non-algebraic solution whereas I ask about a true solution.

I know it is not traditional to ask 2 questions, but I cannot choose which equation to solve, so I will solve very simple first order nonlinear differential equations:

$$y’=x^y\text{ and }y’=y^x$$

Here are the solutions:

$$y+c=\int y^x dx,y+c=\int x^y dx$$

There is also no way I can use the [Frobenius method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) as the serie solution method.

Let’s try to separate the variables ignoring restrictions for now:

$$y’=x^y\implies \ln(y’)=y\ln(x)\implies \log_x(y’)=y\implies y’^\frac1y=x\mathop\implies^{\frac d{dx}}1=\frac{y’(x)^{\frac1y-1}(yy’’-y’^2\ln(y’))}{y^2} $$$$y’=y^x\implies y’^\frac1 x=y\implies \log_y(y’)=\frac{\ln(y’)}{\ln(y)} \mathop\implies^{\frac d{dx}} 1=\frac{y’’}{\ln(y)y’}-\frac{\ln(y’)y’}{\ln^2(y)y}$$

Here is the solution set family and differential curves for $y’=x^y$:

[image]

[image]

Here is the solution set family for $y’=y^x$:

[image]

[image]
How do I solve for $y’=x^y$ and $y’=y^x$ for $y$ explicitly? Any series solution is appreciated. If there is a closed form, then please also write it even though it seems unlikely.

Here is some progress on $y’=x^y$ using the fact that $$x^{\sum\limits_{n\ge0} A_n}=\prod_{n\ge0} x^{A_n}:$$

$$y=\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n\implies \sum_{n\ge1} a_n nx^{n-1}-\prod_{n\ge0} x^{a_n x^n} =0\implies a_1 +2 a_2 x+3 a_3x^2+…-x^{a_0}x^{a_1x}x^{a_2 x^2}\cdot …=0$$

If we were to assume that $\{a_n\}=0$, then this would not work as we have the coefficients in the exponent.

For the other differential equation, one can find the following power series using an experimental infinite [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). I will also use the aforementioned Pi Product notation and factorial definition of the multinational for a representation in terms of more common functions. $n_m$ is just the mth index with the condition that the sum of all infinite number of indices is $x$. There may be a typo:

$$y’=y^x,y=\sum_{n\ge0} a_n x^n\implies\sum_{n\ge1} a_n nx^{n-1}=\left(\sum_{n\ge0}a_n x^n\right)^x\implies \sum_{n\ge1} a_n nx^{n-1}-\sum_{\sum\limits_{m\ge1} n_m=x}\frac{x!\prod\limits_{t\ge0} a_t^{n_m}x^{tn_m}}{\prod\limits_{k\ge 1}n_m!}=0$$

Here is an attempt to put $y’=x^y$ into a more manageable form using a similar method as @Cesareo’s keeping restrictions in mind. This is the corrected answer:

$$y’=x^y\implies y’’=x^{y-1}(x\ln(x)y’+y)\implies y’=x^y=\frac{xy’’}{x\ln(x)y’+y}\implies xy’’=x\ln(x)y’^2+yy’\implies\boxed{ xy’’-x\ln(x)y’^2-yy’=0}$$

which has no apparent solution so ho would I solve $$xy’’-x\ln(x)y’^2-yy’=0$$

I can think of a power series which may or may not need $2$ different indices:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n n(n-1)x^{n-1}-x\ln(x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n nx^{n-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n nx^{n-1}=0$$

We are so close to solving, so do you have any ideas? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: I've found [this](https://homepages.bluffton.edu/~nesterd/apps/slopefields.html) site useful for plotting ode solutions

Comment: @Nyra It only works for 1st order ones, but I have used it for the question.

Comment: So like a combined ode   $\; y'^2-x^2=0 $ for two separate odes $ y'+x=0, y'-x = 0 ?$

Comment: @Narasimham That ODE did not appear in the question and zero product property. The question just asks for the solution to $y’=x^y$ and $y’=y^x$. Do you mean solving $(y’-y^x)(y’-x^y)=0$? Thanks for the clever insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the ODE $y'=y^x$.

Deriving once and substituting $y^x$ we get

$$
y'' = y'\left(\ln y + x\frac{y'}{y}\right)
$$

deriving again and substituting $\ln y$ we get

$$
x y'(x)^4-y(x) y'(x)^2 \left(x y''(x)+2 y'(x)\right)+y(x)^2 \left(y'''(x) y'(x)-y''(x)^2\right)=0
$$

now calling $y_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^n$ and considering $a_0,a_1,a_2$ as initial conditions we can build a series representation to $y(x)$. Follows a MATHEMATICA script which performs this task.

```
Clear[y]
ode = x y'[x]^4 - y[x] y'[x]^2 (2 y'[x] + x y''[x]) + y[x]^2 (-y''[x]^2 + y'[x] y'''[x])
n = 16;
xmax = 1.5;
y0 = 2.0;
delta = 0.01;
soly = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^x, y[0] == y0}, y, {x, 0, xmax}][[1]];
gr0 = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. soly], {x, 0, xmax}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
dy0 = Evaluate[y[x]^x /. soly] /. {x -> 0};
d2y0 = ((Evaluate[y[x]^x /. soly] /. {x -> delta}) - dy0)/delta/2;
cinits = {Subscript[a, 0] -> y0, Subscript[a, 1] -> dy0, Subscript[a, 2] -> d2y0};
y[x_] := Sum[Subscript[a, k] x^k, {k, 0, n}]
A = Table[Subscript[a, k] , {k, 0, n}];
coefs = Take[CoefficientList[ode, x], {1, n - 2}];
vars = Take[A, {4, n + 1}];
sol = Solve[coefs == 0, vars][[1]];
y0 = y[x] /. sol /. cinits
gr1 = Plot[y0, {x, 0, xmax}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dotted, Red}];
Show[gr0, gr1]
```

Attached a plot showing the series approximation (dotted red) in comparison with the integrated result (blue), for $y(0) = 2$.

[image]

NOTE

The series convergence radius depends strongly on $y(0)$ as can be observed in the following plot.

[image]

EDIT

Introduced the series for $n = 20$ and $y(0) = 2$

$$
y_{20}(x) = 0.0000102062 x^{20}+0.0000208849 x^{19}\\
       +0.0000331216x^{18}+0.0000669035 x^{17}\\
       +0.000107192 x^{16}+0.000214423 x^{15}\\
       +0.00034596 x^{14}+0.000687509x^{13}\\
       +0.0011134 x^{12}+0.00220569 x^{11}\\
       +0.00357196 x^{10}+0.00708542 x^9\\
       +0.0114163 x^8+0.0228339 x^7\\
       +0.0363035 x^6+0.0742418 x^5\\
       +0.11444 x^4+0.248472x^3\\
       +0.350297 x^2+1. x+2.
$$

EDIT-2

The first formal coefficients read

$$
\cases{
a_3\to \frac{\frac{a_1^3}{a_0}+2 a_2^2}{3 a_1}\\
a_4\to -\frac{a_1^3}{8 a_0^2}+\frac{3 a_2 a_1}{4 a_0}+\frac{a_2^3}{3 a_1^2}\\
a_5\to \frac{2 a_1^7+a_0
   \left(5 a_1-12 a_2\right) a_1^5+28 a_0^2 a_2^2 a_1^3+4 a_0^3 a_2^4}{30 a_0^3 a_1^3}\\
a_6\to \frac{-30 a_1^9+5 a_0 \left(40 a_2-23 a_1\right) a_1^7+10 a_0^2\left(41 a_1-50 a_2\right) a_2 a_1^5+600 a_0^3 a_2^3 a_1^3+32 a_0^4 a_2^5}{720 a_0^4 a_1^4}\\
a_7\to \frac{36 a_1^{11}+3 a_0 \left(59 a_1-90 a_2\right)
   a_1^9+6 a_0^2 \left(20 a_1^2-147 a_2 a_1+130 a_2^2\right) a_1^7+12 a_0^3 \left(109 a_1-90 a_2\right) a_2^2 a_1^5+744 a_0^4 a_2^4 a_1^3+16 a_0^5a_2^6}{1260 a_0^5 a_1^5}
}
$$

EDIT-3

Regarding the series expansion for the ODE

$$
y'(x) = x^{y(x)}
$$

after unsuccessful trials with series Frobenius inspired, we try to develop a Taylor series such as

$$
y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{y^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k
$$

with $y(x_0)= y_0$ the initial condition. So we have

$$
\cases{
 a_0 = y_0\\
 a_1 = \frac{y^{(1)}(x_0)}{1!} = x_0^{y_0}\\
 a_2 = \frac{y^{(2)}(x_0)}{2!} = \frac 12 x_0^{y_0}\left(\frac{y_0}{x_0}+x_0^{y_0}\ln x_0\right)\\
 a_3 = \frac{1}{3!}x_0^{y_0-2}\left(y_0(y_0-1)+2x_0^{2(y_0+1)}\ln^2 x_0-x_0^{y_0+1}(3y_0\ln x_0+2)\right)\\
 \vdots
}
$$

This way we produce a  sequence of coefficients $a_k = \Phi_k(x_0,y_0)$ and a Taylor series which converges with a convergence radius depending on the pair $\{x_0,y_0\}$. Follows a MATHEMATICA script which automatizes the procedure

```
Clear["Global`*"]
xmax = 1.4;
y0 = 2;
x0 = 1/2;
d[n_] := D[x^y[x], {x, n}]/n!
soly = NDSolve[{y'[x] == x^y[x], y[x0] == y0}, y, {x, x0, xmax}][[1]];
ymax = Evaluate[y[x] /. soly] /. {x -> xmax}
dy0 = x0^y0;
n = 6;
subs = {y[x] -> y0, y'[x] -> dy0, x -> x0};
d1 = x^y[x];
R = { y'[x] -> d1};
COEFS = {d1 /. subs};
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
 der = D[y[x], {x, k + 1}];
 d1 = D[d1, x]/(k + 1) /. R;
 AppendTo[COEFS, d1 /. subs];
 solD = Solve[der == d1, der][[1]][[1]];
 p1 = First[solD];
 p2 = Last[solD];
 If[k == 0, r1 = {p2 -> p1}, r1 = {solD}];
 AppendTo[R, r1[[1]]];
 ]
COEFS // N
fx = y0 + Sum[COEFS[[k]] (x - x0)^k, {k, 1, Length[COEFS]}] // N
gr0 = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. soly], {x, x0, xmax}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotRange -> All];
Show[gr0, Plot[fx, {x, x0, xmax}], PlotRange -> {y0, ymax}]
Plot[Abs[fx - Evaluate[y[x] /. soly]], {x, x0, xmax}]
```

The following plot shows in red the approximation to the ODE with initial conditions $x_0 = 0.5, y_0 = 2$. Follows also the series approximation

$$
y_7(x) = 0.0124492 (x-0.5)^7+0.0653485 (x-0.5)^6+0.0943313 (x-0.5)^5+0.0166054 (x-0.5)^4+0.290859 (x-0.5)^3+0.478339 (x-0.5)^2+0.25 (x-0.5)+2.
$$

[image]

Comment: I saw the edit. This is a nice solution. I redid the other $y’=x^y$ solution, so I hope it works. Could you please list out the first 5 or so coefficients of the series solution in terms of $c_0,c_1$ etc.? I only have the Wolfram Alpha app and not Mathematica. Thanks!

Comment: Included the approximating series for the case study.

Comment: Is there an explicit for for $a_k$ like an $nth$ derivative etc? I will wait until the bounty ends in case someone else answers, but I will probably award you anyways.

Comment: Last thing, I [plotted](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lfhbvbwrrs) the first 15 terms and the differential equation in the link to desmos. Maybe it is of interest.

Comment: Follows the first seven coefficients. The size grows quickly making impractical to represent higher order coefficients.

Comment: Perfect. This will be a good solution. Thanks again!

Comment: This is *optional*,  but could you please check if $$y’=x^y\implies y’’=x^{y-1}(x\ln(x)y’+y)\implies y’=x^y=\frac{yy’’}{x\ln(x)y’+y}\implies yy’’=y’ (x\ln(x)y’+y) \implies yy’’-x\ln(x)y’^2-y’y=0$$ is correct? It is at the bottom of the question..

Comment: We have $y'' = x^y(\frac yx+y' \ln x)$ or $y'' = y'(\frac yx+y'\ln x)$. Take the log previously at differentiation.

Comment: Good job. You won the bounty. Maybe there is a way to solve $y’=x^y$? This task is optional though.

Comment: $y' = x^y$ resists to a series conventional approach. I hope to obtain some results...

Comment: I hope to see your results, I have created a possible series solution in the question to be solved. Again, this is optional to do. Thanks again.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Included a series approximation to $y' = x^y$.

Comment: I have never thought about using the Taylor Series to solve a differential equation, there should be other uses too. I will add this to my toolbox for solving. Thanks again.