# How to solve this ODE: $y^{(y(x))}(x)=f(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, cauchy-integral-formula, fractional-calculus, fractional-differential-equations

$$\large{\text{Introduction:}}$$

This question will be partly inspired from:

> [Evaluation of $$y’=x^y,y’=y^x$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268995/evaluation-of-y-xy-y-yx)

but what if we made the order of an differential equation equal to the function? Imagine that we had the following linear ordinary differential equation using [nth derivative notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation). In other words, the $y(x)\,th$ derivative of $y(x)$ is $f(x)$. I would have made $f(x)\to f(x,y)$, but that is too hard to solve. Note that $f(x)$ is any continuous infinitely differentiable function:

$$\frac{d^{y(x)}}{dx^{y(x)}}y(x)=\text D^{y(x)}_x y(x)=f(x)\implies y^{(y)}=f(x)\implies y^{(y)}=f$$

$$\large{\text{Specific Values:}}$$

Here are some examples of points:

$$y^{(y(0))}(0)=f(0), y^{\left(y \left(\frac12\right)\right)} \left(\frac12\right)=f\left(\frac12\right) $$

we could also imagine an inverse relation for $y(x)$ called $y^{-1}(x)$:

$$0=f\left(y^{-1}(0)\right), y^{\left(\frac12\right)} \left(\frac12\right) = f\left(y^{-1}\left(\frac12\right) \right),y’(1)=f\left(y^{-1}(1)\right)$$

$$\large{\text{Problem Statement:}}$$

this presents the problem that if $y(x)\not\in\Bbb Z$, then we need a [fractional derivative](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html), but definitions for such derivatives are confusing, so we can use the inverse operation of the fractional derivative which is the [**fractional integral**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) using the corresponding notation in the bolded link:

$$y^{(y)}=f(x)\implies \text I_x^{y(x)}\text D_x^{y(x)}y(x)=\text I_x^{y(x)}f(x)\implies y+c_1=\text I^y_x f(x)$$

$$\large{\text{Integral Method:}}$$

Now let’s use [Cauchy’s Formula for Repeated Integration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) as the definition for the fractional integration as seen in the bolded link:

$$\,_a\text I^n_x g(x)=\frac 1{Γ(n)}\int_a^xg(t)(x-t)^{n-1}dt\implies y+c_1=\,_a \text I^{y(x)}_x f(x)=\frac{1}{Γ(y(x))}\int_a^x f(t)(x-t)^{y(x)-1} dt\implies \boxed{y!+c_0 Γ(y)=\int_{c_1}^x f(t)(x-t)^{y-1} dt}$$

$$\large{\text{Special Case Solution Using Integral method:}}$$

Let’s now solve the $f(x)=1$ case using the conjectured formula:

$$y^{(y(x))}(x)=1\implies (y(x))!+c_0 Γ(y(x))=\int_{c_1}^x (x-t)^{y(x)-1} dt\implies y!+c_0 Γ(y)=\frac{(x-c_1)^y}y\implies \boxed{y!(y+c_0)-(x-c_1)^y=0}\implies x=\sqrt[y]{y!(y+c_0)}+c_1$$

Here is a [complete interactive graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sjn4o7ztog) for this conjectured solution.

Another problem is if the fractional derivative has the same definition using $2$ different operator definitions, like [this one](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2013/279681/).

$$\large{\text{Special Case Using Induction:}}$$

Another way for $f(x)=1$ is the following setting all constants of integration to be $0$ via quick induction:

$$y^{(y(x))}(x)=1\mathop\implies^{n=y(x)} y^{(n)}(x)=1\implies y^{(n-1)}=x,y^{(n-2)}=\frac {x^2}{1\cdot2},y^{(n-3)}=\frac{x^3}{3\cdot2\cdot1}\implies y^{(n-k)}=\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Now let’s set $n=k$:

$$y^{(n-k)}(x)=y^{(n-n)}(x)=y^{(0)}(x)=y(x)=\frac{x^{y(x)}}{(y(x))!}$$

Let’s try to solve for $x$:

$$yx^{-y}=y!$$

but we cannot use the [W-Lambert function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) here. We can also write the *conjectured* solution as:

$$y^{(y)}=1\mathop\implies^? y\ln(x)-\ln(y)-\ln(y!)=0$$

Using an [Inversion theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/InversionFormulas.html) will be cumbersome.

$$\large{\text{Conclusion:}}$$

Is this a correct way to solve $y^{(y)}=f(x)$ and if not, then how? Please correct me and give me feedback!

$$\large{\text{Addendum:}}$$

Also see

> [Solving $y^{(x)}(x)=ax+b$ in closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283166/solving-yxx-axb-in-closed-form-what-function-equals-axb-when-you-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)

for a twin question where a general solution was found. A particular solution for $f(x)=1$ using [round $[x]$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) is:

$$y^{(k)}(x)=1\implies y=\frac{x^k}{k!}\implies y^{(x)}(x)=1\implies y=\frac{x^{[x]}}{[x]!}$$

Following the same logic:

$$y^{(y)}(x)=1\mathop\implies^?y=\frac{x^{[y]}}{[y]!}\iff x=(y[y]!)^\frac1{[y]}$$

[graph here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hcve3vkyoz)

Answer (score 4):

##### Not a complete answer, but a partial answer.

I've asked myself the same question before, but never found a complete solution, so I'd like to share my work on it in the hope that it might help someone. Since nobody has answered yet, I will also share the unfinished one. I hope that's ok.

##### My Work *(the best of it)*

Let's assume that $f$ has a [Maclaurin Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) of the general form $f\left( x \right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( f_{k} \cdot \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \right)$ (Assumption $1.$) and that $f$ can be written as a [Generalized Hypergeometric Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) (I will abbreviate "Generalized Hypergeometric Function" in the following with the abbreviation "GHF".) of the form $f\left( x \right) = \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left( \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, A_{2},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, B_{2},\, \dots,\, B_{q} \end{matrix};\, x \right)$ (Assumption $2.$), then we could try the [Frobenius Method](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html). But before we do that, I would like to mention the nth derivative formula or nth integral formula for monomials that I used:

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D}_{x}^{n}~ \left( x^{m} \right) &= \frac{m!}{\left( m - n \right)!} \cdot x^{m - n}\\
\operatorname{I}_{x}^{n}~ \left( x^{m} \right) &= \frac{m!}{\left( m + n \right)!} \cdot x^{m + n} \tag{1.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Rewrite it a bit:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D}_{x}^{y\left( x \right)} \left( y\left( x \right) \right) &= f\left( x \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= \operatorname{I}_{x}^{n}~ \left( f\left( x \right) \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Substitute $f\left( x \right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( f_{k} \cdot \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \right)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= \operatorname{I}_{x}^{n}~ \left( f\left( x \right) \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= \operatorname{I}_{x}^{n}~ \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( f_{k} \cdot \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \right) \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( f_{k} \cdot \frac{\frac{k!}{\left( k + y\left( x \right) \right)!} \cdot x^{k + y\left( x \right)}}{k!} \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( f_{k} \cdot \frac{x^{k + y\left( x \right)}}{\left( k + y\left( x \right) \right)!} \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{f_{k} \cdot x^{y\left( x \right)}}{\left( k + y\left( x \right) \right)!} \cdot x^{k} \right) \tag{2.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

We can rewrite formula $2.$ to the generalized series expansion $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( c_{k} \cdot \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \right)$ ([General Hypergeometric Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricSeries.html)) of the [GHF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html):
$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{f_{k} \cdot x^{y\left( x \right)}}{\left( k + y\left( x \right) \right)!} \cdot x^{k} \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{f_{k} \cdot x^{y\left( x \right)} \cdot k!}{\left( k + y\left( x \right) \right)!} \cdot \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \right)\\
y\left( x \right) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left( c_{k} \cdot \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \right) \tag{3.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

If we try to simplify formula $3.$ series to a [GHF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html), we can get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{c_{k + 1}}{c_{k}} &= \frac{\frac{f_{k + 1} \cdot x^{y\left( x \right)} \cdot \left( k + 1 \right)!}{\left( k + 1 + y\left( x \right) \right)!}}{\frac{f_{k} \cdot x^{y\left( x \right)} \cdot k!}{\left( k + y\left( x \right) \right)!}}\\
\frac{c_{k + 1}}{c_{k}} &= \frac{f_{k + 1} \cdot x^{y\left( x \right)} \cdot \left( k + 1 \right)! \cdot \left( k + y\left( x \right) \right)!}{f_{k} \cdot x^{y\left( x \right)} \cdot k! \cdot \left( k + 1 + y\left( x \right) \right)!}\\
\frac{c_{k + 1}}{c_{k}} &= \frac{f_{k + 1} \cdot \left( k + 1 \right)}{f_{k} \cdot \left( k + 1 + y\left( x \right) \right)}\\
\frac{c_{k + 1}}{c_{k}} &= \frac{f_{k + 1}}{f_{k}} \cdot \frac{k + 1}{k + 1 + y\left( x \right)} \tag{4.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Via the Assumption $2.$ that $f$ can be represented as a [GHF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) of the form $f\left( x \right) = \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left( \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, A_{2},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, B_{2},\, \dots,\, B_{q} \end{matrix};\, x \right)$ it follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{f_{k + 1}}{f_{k}} &= \frac{\left( k + A_{1} \right) \cdots \left( k + A_{p} \right)}{\left( k + B_{1} \right) \cdots \left( k + B_{q} \right) \cdot \left( k + 1 \right)} \tag{5.1.}\\
f\left( x \right) &= \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left( \begin{matrix}
A_{1},\, A_{2},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, B_{2},\, \dots,\, B_{q}
\end{matrix};\, x \right) \tag{5.2.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Via combining the formula $4.$ and the formula $5.1$ we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{c_{k + 1}}{c_{k}} &= \frac{f_{k + 1}}{f_{k}} \cdot \frac{k + 1}{k + 1 + y\left( x \right)}\\
\frac{c_{k + 1}}{c_{k}} &= \frac{\left( k + A_{1} \right) \cdots \left( k + A_{p} \right)}{\left( k + B_{1} \right) \cdots \left( k + B_{q} \right) \cdot \left( k + 1 \right)} \cdot \frac{k + 1}{k + 1 + y\left( x \right)}\\
\frac{c_{k + 1}}{c_{k}} &= \frac{\left( k + A_{1} \right) \cdots \left( k + A_{p} \right) \cdot \left( k + 1 \right)}{\left( k + B_{1} \right) \cdots \left( k + B_{q} \right) \cdot \left( k + 1 + y\left( x \right) \right) \cdot \left( k + 1 \right)}\\
\end{align*}
$$

We can combine all of this into a [GHF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html):
$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= \operatorname{_{p + 1}F_{q + 1}}\left( \begin{matrix}
1,\, A_{1},\, A_{2},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ y\left( x \right) + 1,\, B_{1},\, B_{2},\, \dots,\, B_{q}
\end{matrix};\, x \right) \tag{6.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Leonard Euler found the following [Integral Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Euler%27s_integral_transform) for this form of the [GHF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html):
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{_{A + 1}F_{B + 1}}\left[ \begin{matrix} c,\, a_{1},\, \dots,\, a_{A}\\ d,\, b_{1},\, \dots,\, b_{B}\\ \end{matrix};\, z \right] &= \frac{\Gamma\left( d \right)}{\Gamma\left( c \right) \cdot \Gamma\left( d - c \right)} \cdot \int_{0}^{1} t^{c - 1} \cdot \left( 1 - t \right)^{d - c - 1} \cdot \operatorname{_{A}F_{B}}\left[ \begin{matrix} a_{1},\, \dots,\, a_{A}\\ b_{1},\, \dots,\, b_{B}\\ \end{matrix};\, t \cdot z \right]\, \operatorname{d}t \tag{7.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

With the formula $6.$ and [Eulers Integral Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Euler%27s_integral_transform) (formula $7.$) we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= \frac{\Gamma\left( y\left( x \right) + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( 1 \right) \cdot \Gamma\left( y\left( x \right) + 1 - 1 \right)} \cdot \int_{0}^{1} t^{1 - 1} \cdot \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) + 1 - 1 - 1} \cdot \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left[ \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, \dots,\, B_{q}\\ \end{matrix};\, t \cdot x \right]\, \operatorname{d}t\\
y\left( x \right) &= \frac{\Gamma\left( y\left( x \right) + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( 1 \right) \cdot \Gamma\left( y\left( x \right) \right)} \cdot \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left[ \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, \dots,\, B_{q}\\ \end{matrix};\, t \cdot x \right]\, \operatorname{d}t\\
y\left( x \right) &= \frac{y\left( x \right)}{\Gamma\left( 1 \right)} \cdot \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left[ \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, \dots,\, B_{q}\\ \end{matrix};\, t \cdot x \right]\, \operatorname{d}t\\
\Gamma\left( 1 \right) &= \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left[ \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, \dots,\, B_{q}\\ \end{matrix};\, t \cdot x \right]\, \operatorname{d}t\\
1 &= \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left[ \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, \dots,\, B_{q}\\ \end{matrix};\, t \cdot x \right]\, \operatorname{d}t \tag{8.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

The best result I got was this:
$$\boxed{1 = \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left[ \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, \dots,\, B_{q}\\ \end{matrix};\, t \cdot x \right]\, \operatorname{d}t}$$

I don't know if everything I've done is correct, but I hope it can help or at least give an idea for a solution.

*Edit*

I just realized that we can simplify the formula $8.$ even further. Again using Assumption $2.$ that $f$ can be represented as a [GHF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) of the form $f\left( x \right) = \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left( \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, A_{2},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, B_{2},\, \dots,\, B_{q} \end{matrix};\, x \right)$ and the relation $5.2.$, we can rewrite it as:
$$
\begin{align*}
1 &= \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot \operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}\left[ \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, \dots,\, B_{q}\\ \end{matrix};\, t \cdot x \right]\, \operatorname{d}t\\
1 &= \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) - 1} \cdot f\left( t \cdot x \right)\, \operatorname{d}t\\
\end{align*}
$$

So a better result I got is this:
$$\boxed{1 = \int_{0}^{1} \left( 1 - t \right)^{y\left( x \right) - 1}\ \cdot f\left( t \cdot x \right)\, \operatorname{d}t}$$

Comment: When you wrote $\text I_x^n(x^m)$, one can find a general solution since there can be $n$ constants of integration.

Comment: In the last expression, this seems to imply a great deal of nonuniqueness of the nonhomogenous problem, as any function $f$ such that $\int_0^1f(x)dx=1$ yields the solution $y=1$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Are you're sure about your solution for $y$? Wolfram|Alpha finds [the solution $1=\int_0^1 (1-t)^{y-1} tx dt\implies 1=\frac{x}{y + y^{2}}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+%3D%3D+Integrate%5B%281+-+t%29%5E%28y%5Bx%5D+-+1%29+x+t%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D) and [thus $y=\frac12\left(\sqrt{4x+1}-1\right)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5Bx+%3D%3D+y+%2B+y%5E2%2C+y%2C+MaxExtraConditions+-%3E+Automatic%5D).

Comment: @KevinDietrich in that case, $y^{(y(2))}(2)=y’(2)=\frac13\ne2$ [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5h87nxchvp)

Comment: Maybe the formula for $f(x) = x$ doesn't work because of the conditions given, like the Assumption $2.$ that $f$ can be represented like $f\left( x \right) = \operatorname{_{p}F_{q }}\left( \begin{matrix} A_{1},\, A_{2},\, \dots,\, A_{p}\\ B_{1},\, B_{2},\, \dots,\, B_{q} \end{matrix};\, x \right)$, but $f(x) = x$ cannot be represented in this way.

Comment: @KevinDietrich $f=\,_1 F_1(0;1;x)=1$, so $y^{(y(1))}(1)=y’(1)=0\ne f=1$, so maybe $A_j,B_j>0$. Can you give a working example with your formula if you have time?